# Magento fetch product description in tabs via Ajax

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax

I want to fetch the product description via Ajax in Magento product details page. Please guide me how I can do it. I am using Magento CE 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ajax code in view.phtml(`app/design/frontend/youpackage/yourtemplate/temaplate/catalog/product/`) 
file

```
<script>
new Ajax.Request("youhost/custommodule/",{
    method:'get',
    parameters:{'id':<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId();?>},
     onLoading:function() { //alert('pleasewait'); 
                            },
        onSuccess: function(transport)    {
            if(200 == transport.status)    {
                var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                if(json.hasDes==1)
                document.getElementById("").innerHtml(json.des);

            }
        },
        onFailure: function(){ }
    });
</script>
```

Create a module with controllers

First of all create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/ - See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

and code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Amit_Custommodule>
                <codePool>community</codePool>
                <active>true</active>
            </Amit_Custommodule>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

2.create config.xml in `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/` 
and code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <!-- start of routers
    -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custommodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                    <frontName>custommodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </custommodule>
        </routers>
      </frontend>
</config>
```

And

Here above code  custommodule is routers ,If   you want to any url from this modules then url  like  yousiteurl/custommodule

create an controller,which is generally called as routers

`IndexController.php` path is `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/controllers/`
and code

```
<?php
class Amit_Custommodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function indexAction(){
$result=array()
$result['hasDes']=0;
$id =$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($id);
    if($product->getId()):
    $result['hasDes']=1;
    $result['des']=$product->getDescription();
    endif;
 $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
}
```

Comment: I did all the steps as above. I tried to check it by loading it this way - http://site/custommodule/?id=521  and its returning this -  {"hasDes":1,"des":null}. I can confirm the product has description.

Comment: Gotcha! the was a typo in your code - '$product->getDesciption();' changed it to getDescription(); and it worked!

Comment: Thanks @sunny155 , what is   small mistake.but is makes hug issue

Comment: Got another issue, Its not able to output it in the desired location. I don't know why. I created a test div with an ID but its not outputting the ajax data there - document.getElementById("test155").innerHtml(json.des);